# QT QML WebView onPause Android

Tags: android, qt, webview, qml

I create WebView in QML in QT and after some actions it paused (D WebView : onPause). How I can detect it and resume WebView?

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtWebView::initialize();
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtWebView 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: app
    visible: true

    WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: true
        url: "http://mail.ru"
    }
}
```

**manifest**

```
...
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
....
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Can you be more precise? Or add code sample?

Comment: I add code. The problem is that there is no way to call onResume method on webView if it paused.

Comment: In java (Android studio) if you create WebView, you can detect this events and call webView.onPause() or webView.onResume to pause or resume it.

Comment: Please, let us know some more information. Does the pause happen while the application is in foreground or does it not resume after switching from background to foreground? What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: QT 5.7, Android 6.0 (on KitKat 4.4. this problem does not exist). My app is Launcher and It happens after I press home button (if my app is default launcher and it already running) .

Comment: According to the code [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebview.git/tree/src/webview/qwebview_android.cpp#n239) resume happens automatically, as the app is brought to foreground. I could have guessed it was an API level issue (see the code) but the different behaviour between 4.4 and 6.0 sound more of an Android issue. I can't carry out some tests right now, sorry.